# AJAX call returns 0

Tags: jquery, ajax

In spite of many similar posts, all the proposed solutions didn't work for me, so here we are.

I have the following script :

```
jQuery('#term').keyup(ajaxChange);

        function ajaxChange(){
            var newFormChange = jQuery("#term").val();
            alert (newFormChange);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                action: "my_test_action",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: newFormChange,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        return false;
        }
```

And the PHP looks like this :

```
function my_test_action() {

    $var = "this is a test";
    wp_send_json($var);

    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_test_action', 'my_test_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_test_action', 'my_test_action' );
```

I've also tried : `echo json_encode($var)` or `echo $var`, instead of `wp_send_json()` but the function always returns 0 in the browser console !

My other AJAX calls work, for instance I have another one that calls a PHP script which calls a WP Query and displays some posts, it works fine.

**EDIT :** Here is how my script is included :

```
 function add_js() {

         if (is_page_template()) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustomscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/mycustomscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

            wp_localize_script('mycustomscript', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js');
```

I think the problem comes from the `newFormChange` variable, because `jQuery(this).serialize();` didn't work in the first place, because the form is not submitted but only one of its fields changes. So I replaced it by var `newFormChange = jQuery("#term").val();` but then maybe there is a problem with `url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"`

Where am I mistaken ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the `action` should be inside the `data` key. In your post request there is no key named as  `action` therefore, the callback function is never being called.

Consider this example:-

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: { 
        action: "my_test_action",
        form_data : newFormChange
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Also Note:** Never use relative Ajax URL like `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. You can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). See these [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: well done, it works ! but it's strange, I have another script where action is outside, and it works though !

Comment: You are welcome :) Nope you need to double check it. `action` is WordPress made thing, and rest of the parameters belongs to jQuery. You can see here [`jQuery Ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `action` is not a valid key.

Comment: if I write alert(newFormChange) I see something like "term=anything&action=my_test_action. Hence, the "WP made thing" action is passed like another POST variable ? I have one more extra question : if I use $_POST['term'] in my_test_action(), it is not recognized. Though it is the proper way to retrieve POST variables with this method. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure where did you place alert! but if you see `term=anything&action=my_test_action` on alert that is GET request. So you will be able to access the variable using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` but I really wonder why you are seeing query string instead of js object.

Comment: I called the serialize() method on newFormChange then I placed the alert just after that. The funny thing is that it displays what I wrote above, even if action is defined within the data. I applied your recommandations on my other scripts and I'm no longer able do retrieve data with $_POST[]. Strange !

Comment: got it, it was a parasite hidden field. I'm really sorry, my mistake. Still, I can no longer access my $_POST[] data. When data was only "newFormChange" I could access it "normally". Now the only variable I can access is  $_POST['newFormChange']. Shall I parse it in order to retrieve the individual fields ?

Comment: Yes exactly! you've to parse it. To see the structure of data you are receiving just print it. e.g. `print_r($_POST);` and you will see how you can access it. If it is query string use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Hope it helps :)

Comment: it does, thanks again ! I was asking for some help elsewhere on SE about this specific topic, and I was told to use serializeArray() in order to be able to get my $_POST[] parameters properly. However, I still can't. Do you have some advice for this ? Thanks a lot http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225111/retrieve-post-data-from-ajax-call

Comment: Gossssh -- I was passing in action as its own property not within data, Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with at `url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"`, instead try adding the full path:

```
function addajaxurl() {
    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addajaxurl' );
```

and call the variable in your ajax function:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: newFormChange,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks I'll test it ! but my other AJAX calls do work, it's strange...! see my edit above, I have almost the same thing than you. Besides, if the .php url wasn't found, it would have returned an error in the console, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Yeah it seems the error is with `action`, try removing that

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the action parameter.
In your javascript function please try:

```
var newFormChange = jQuery("#term").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: "my_test_action",
                        newFormChange: newFormChange
                    }   ,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                  alert(data);


                });
```

You should also remove  die(); from your php function. It is already in the wp_send_json.