# Retrieve POST data from AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following `JS` script :

```
jQuery('#form-recherche').submit(ajaxSubmit);

        function ajaxSubmit(){

            var newFormRecherche = jQuery(this).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"post",
                data: { 
                    action: "mon_action",
                    newFormRecherche: newFormRecherche,
                },

                url: ajaxurl,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

        return false;
        }
```

On `PHP` side :

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

    function mon_action() {

        if (isset($_POST["newFormRecherche"])) {
            $field1= $_POST["field1"];
            $field2= $_POST["field2"];
        }
    }
```

As you guessed, I'm able to access `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]` while I can't retrieve `$_POST["field1"]` nor `$_POST["field2"]`.

jQuery `serialize()` works properly : I tested `newFormRecherche` var with an alert and it is displayed under the right form : `$field1=whatever&$field2=anything`.

Normally, I shouldn't have to parse the results in order to access the $_POST[] variables, according to what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form), but obviously it's not working. Where does this problem come from ? Should I use something else than `data` to pass my arguments ?

**EDIT** : `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]` exists on PHP side, and contains the expected string `$field1=whatever&$field2=anything`.

**EDIT #2** : Here is an update, according to the interesting remark from @czerspalace and the very detailed post from @bosco. I try here to put what they said in a nutshell, and give some solutions.

The problem here was a double serialization, one made "by hand", one made by jQuery while making the AJAX call. The fact that the `$_POST[]` vars can't be properly retrieved on server side comes from `data`, that has to match the Wordpress formalism, that is to say : an `action` (which is a PHP function) and the data sent (usually, from a form).

- Solution by @Bosco -
  Use the jQuery method `serializeArray()`. In this case, the data sent is composed of 2 objects. In order to properly retrieve the fields on server side, I have to handle an associative array like this : `$_POST['newFormRecherche'][0]['name']` and `$_POST['newFormRecherche'][0]['value']`. Same thing for the other fields (replacing [0] by other numbers). To solve that, @Bosco proposes below the `formFieldsToObject` function which is called on the data, when performing the AJAX call.
- Solution by @czerspalace -
  Use the `serialize()` jQuery method, and make a manual deserialization on server side, using `parse_str( $_POST[ 'newFormRecherche' ], $newFormRecherche );` in order to be able to retrieve the fields I want : $newFormRecherche['field1'],...and so on.

In both cases, the data on server side has to be properly sanitized, as data sent by an user via forms always must be. It implies : checking field types, checking (and even truncate) fields length..., in other words : never trust the user.

**EDIT #3** : In the case you use `FormData`, make sure you add this line within your AJAX call : `processData: false,`. However, I didn't implement a full solution with this technique.

Comment: What if you try `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]["field1"]` anf  `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]["field2"]`

Comment: I get a warning at the involved lines : Warning: Illegal string offset 'field1'...

Comment: please do the minimum of debugging before to ask a question. that means looking at every variable (like `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]`) to see if the contains the expected values and writing these values in the question. look also this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: You probably need to parse the `$_POST['newFormRecherche']` like `parse_str($_POST["newFormRecherche"], $output);` and then try `$output["field1"]`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works ! though I don't understand why I couldn't access the variables "normally". In a previous version of this function, "action" vas outside the data parameter, and I was able to retrieve $_POST['field1'].

Comment: A solid summary in **EDIT #2**, @Fafanellu! On a final note, I did add a little `formFieldsToObject()` function to the **jQuery** solution which should fix the gross `$_POST['newFormRecherche'][0]['name']` / `$_POST['newFormRecherche'][0]['value']` problem =]

Comment: nicely done, a clean and simple solution ! why such a function doesn't exist natively ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem

"Serialization" is the act of turning a data-object into a string-representation. jQuery automatically serializes the `data` property before sending an AJAX request. The server then deserializes the `GET` querystring from the URL, and the request body for `POST` requests before populating PHP's request variables.

Your code functioned as expected when `data` consisted solely of your serialized form data (i.e. `data: newFormRecherche,`) as the data was already in a string format, and thus could not be further serialized. The server's deserialization pass then properly parsed your form data into request variables.

However, when the `data` argument is an object jQuery must serialize it in order to pass it to a server. As a property of that object, your pre-serialized form data is handled as though it were any other string - specifically, it is escaped in such a manner to prevent it from being "mistaken" for a serialized object. So when the server then deserializes `data`, `newFormRecherche` is deserialized into the value which jQuery originally received it as - that is, a string - and thus requires the second pass of deserialization that @czerspalace alluded to in the comments in order to produce an associative array of form data.

---

### Solutions

#### - jQuery

To prevent the double-serialization of your form data, acquire it as an array of key/value pairs instead of a serialized string by invoking [jQuery's `.serializeArray()` method](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) on the form element instead of `.serialize()`.

While jQuery is capable of properly serializing this key/value-array-format of `data`, it seems it chokes when such an array is nested as property of a `data` object (instead sending the string `'[object Object]'` in place of each key/value pair), as well as when attempting to nest such a key/value-array inside another. As such, I think the best way to send form data as a part of multi-dimensional data is to convert the key/value-array into an object.

All of this can be done as follows:

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
  var newFormRecherche = jQuery( this ).serializeArray();

  jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: { 
      action: "mon_action",
      newFormRecherche: formFieldsToObject( newFormRecherche )
    },
    url: ajaxurl,
    success: function( response ){
      console.log( response );
    }
  });

  return false;
}

function formFieldsToObject( fields ) {
  var product = {};

  for( var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ ) {
    var field = fields[ i ];

    if( ! product.hasOwnProperty( field.name ) ) {
      product[ field.name ] = field.value;
    }
    else {
      if( ! product[ field.name ] instanceof Array )
        product[ field.name ] = [ product[ field.name ] ];

      product[ field.name ].push( field.value );
    }
  }

  return product;
}
```

#### - HTML5 `FormData`

Alternately, if you need only support modern browsers or don't mind loading a polyfill to support older ones, just use [the `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to pass your form data as a proper data object:

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
  var newFormRecherche = new FormData( this );

  jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: { 
      action: "mon_action",
      newFormRecherche: newFormRecherche
    },
    url: ajaxurl,
    success: function( response ){
      console.log( response );
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

#### - Server-Side Double-Deserialization

As @czerspalace suggests in the comments, accounting for the double-serialization by simply manually deserializing the form data on the server is also an entirely valid solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

function mon_action() {
  if( isset( $_POST[ 'newFormRecherche' ] ) ) {
    parse_str( $_POST[ 'newFormRecherche' ], $newFormRecherche );
    die( json_encode( $newFormRecherche ) );
  }
}
```

I'm inclined to think that the other approaches are more "professional" in that all of the data sent to the server is packaged in a consistent and expected format - no additional "decoding" is necessary on the server's part, improving code modularity.

But code modularity and subjective "professionalism" aren't always the most important factors - sometimes the most simple solution is the most appropriate.

---

> Remember to [validate and sanitize request
>   data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)
>   on the server before you use it in order to mitigate security vulnerabilities.

Comment: thank you very much for this clear and clean explanation, I understand where the problem was now ! Though, you wrote that "jQuery will properly serialize these key/value pairs into request variables", but I still can't access them and I can no longer parse them as they aren't strings anymore. What is the cleanest solution to retrieve their values ?

Comment: @Fafanellu it seems I gave jQuery more credit than is due - it doesn't like it when you use that key/value array in nested data structures, and actually fails to serialize it properly in such situations. I've added a little helper function that should set everything straight - the data should be accessible in PHP via a properly structured `$_POST` array, i.e. `$_POST["newFormRecherche"]["field1"]`. You can `echo json_encode( $_POST );` in your AJAX handler, or `var_dump( $_POST );` to see the exact structure of the form data.

Comment: thanks for this very interesting topic ! I've updated my initial post to take into account the constructive comments made here

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of die( json_encode( $newFormRecherche ) ) ?

Comment: That's just a temporary placeholder for whatever your code would be =) . `die()` immediately ends a PHP script's execution, optionally `echo()`ing an argument, if supplied - so it will immediately end the AJAX request, responding with the form-data that the server received as a JSON object (though probably with the wrong `Content-Type` header, but jQuery shouldn't mind). In combination the `success` callback you specified in your JavaScript which `console.log()`s the server's response, you should end up with a nice, navigable readout of the form data in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: ok thanks ! actually I didn't write the whole PHP code, but there was an empty die() in the end. If I understand, the purpose is to end the AJAX request as soon as possible in order to send data back.

Comment: Pretty much! [This Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) touches on it, briefly. The general idea is that after you've handled the AJAX request and `echo()`d a response, there's not much of a reason to finish WordPress's execution. If WordPress is allowed to continue to run as it normally would, there's a risk that code executed after your AJAX handler will `echo()` something else onto the response, which would likely break your JavaScript when your `success` callback tries to process it.

Comment: [`wp_die()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) is considered a better alternative to `die()`. It's rare to use either outside of AJAX handlers except for temporary troubleshooting - there is almost always a better way to handle a problem or report an error then to simply kill script execution!

Comment: once more, thanks for your clear explanations ! I've updated my original post in order to include your suggestions :)